# Trouble integrating IvoryCKEditorBundle with Symfony forms

Tags: php, symfony-2.7

I'm using `symfony 2.7` and `php 5.6.25`. I installed `IvoryCKEditorBundle`, [using this documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/index.html). I want to integrate `ckeditor` as a type in my formtype like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder->add('description', 'ckeditor', array(
        'config' => array('toolbar' => 'full'),
    ))
   ...
}
```

I this is the result I get (I don't have any errors in my console):
[image]

Comment: Hey, did you find something ?

Answer (score 4):

Install the assets:

```
php app/console assets:install --relative
```